# Intervention package make method over http not https?

Tags: php, laravel-5, intervention

I'm using the [Intervention](https://github.com/Intervention/image) image manipulation package and Laravel to upload and crop some pictures. My entire site is served over SSL, and it appears that the make method (used to open a file) only works over HTTP, not HTTPS.  Is this expected behavior?  If so, yuk.

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;

// fails when I open over https
//$image_url = "https://mysite.app/avatars/a6-7edaf.jpg"; 

// works when I open over http
//$image_url = "http://mysite.app/avatars/a6-7edaf.jpg"; 

$manager = new ImageManager();
$image = $manager->make($image_url)->encode('jpg');
```

Error message when attempting to make/open over https:

```
NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 68:
Unable to init from given url (https://mysite.app/avatars/a6-7edaf.jpg).
```

I can open the image just fine when I directly browse to it, I just can't read/make the file from within Intervention when I pass the https URL.

Comment: Is the certificate valid? And assuming this is running on the same server, why would you incur the HTTP overhead when you could access the file directly via the filesystem? `curl https://mysite.app/avatars/a6-7edaf.jpg` from where you're running the code and see if there are cert issues.

Comment: You are indeed correct -- I should have mentioned that I was using my local dev environment (no cert) and should have also tried in prod (with cert).  I just hate pushing to prod (to test) without being able to test locally.  Thanks for the pointer.